# AVG join result in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join

I've got a query with `avg` results. In another table I have the results of that
`avg` result in text.

Right now this is my query:

```
select round(avg(breed_ratings.rating)) as result, breed_ratings.score_name, count(*) as total, breeds.name_en
from breed_ratings
inner join breeds on breeds.id = breed_ratings.breed_id 
where breeds.id = 188
group by score_name, breeds.name_en
```

The rating_result table looks like this:

```
id
rating
result_text
```

How can I get the `result_text` in this query?

Please help me out.

--EDIT

I need to get the `result` from the image below in text. 
[image]

So I have another table where this is stored I need to get the result_nl where it matches the rating:

[image]

Desired result (if rating is 5):

```
result: 5
score_name: ADULT_FRIENDLY
total: 117
name_en: American Staffordshire Terrier
result_nl: I am extremely dominant
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Please see my edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to `join` the average to the first rating in `rating_results` where the average is bigger than the listed rating there.  If so:

```
select br.*, rr.result_text
from (select round(avg(br.rating)) as result, br.score_name, count(*) as total, b.name_en
      from breed_ratings br join
           breeds b
           on b.id = br.breed_id 
      where b.id = 188
      group by br.score_name, b.name_en
     ) br left join
     (select rr.*, lead(rr.rating) over (order by rr.rating) as next_rating
      from rating_result rr
     ) rr
     on br.result >= rr.rating and
        (br.result < rr.next_rating or rr.next_rating is null)
```

Comment: thanks for helping out. Your answer is too complicated I only need to join on the AVG result. Please see my edit in the question.

Comment: If you have any other question please let me know.

Comment: @Jenssen . . . This answers your question.  I have no idea what *you* mean by "too complicated", but this should work.